# why innodb use gen_clust_index instead of table lock when table have no any index?

Tags: mysql, innodb

My mysql version is 5.7. I try to test some case about innodb lock.I know:
a. query using table lock when table have no any index.
b. table have no any index, innodb will auto create gen_clust_index.
c. gen_clust_index is row lock.

My example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_order`;
CREATE TABLE tbl_order (
    `order_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
    `product_name` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
) Engine=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO tbl_order(`order_id`, `product_name`) VALUES(1, ' zhangsan1'), (1, 'lisi2');
```

Client session operation:

```
SET autocommit=0;
SELECT @@autocommit;
SELECT * FROM tbl_order WHERE product_name='zhangsan1' FOR UPDATE;
```

InnoDB engine information as follow:

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 36630
Purge done for trx's n:o < 36627 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 2
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 36629, ACTIVE 14 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 11, OS thread handle 9336, query id 376 localhost ::1 root
TABLE LOCK table `index_test`.`tbl_order` trx id 36629 lock mode IX
RECORD LOCKS space id 284 page no 3 n bits 72 index GEN_CLUST_INDEX of table `index_test`.`tbl_order` trx id 36629 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 6; hex 000000567501; asc    Vu ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000008f11; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 30000001190858; asc 0     X;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 4: len 5; hex 6c69736932; asc lisi2;;

Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 6; hex 000000567500; asc    Vu ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000008f0f; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 2f000001150932; asc /     2;;
 3: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
 4: len 9; hex 7a68616e6773616e31; asc zhangsan1;;
```

I know innodb use gen_clust_index and lock all index record for my query. I don't understand it. My question:

```
1. why my query use gen_clust_index instead table lock?
2. how do innodb know lock all record when it use gen_clust_index?
```

Comment: With InnoDB you [have an index whether you specify one or not](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html).

Comment: @yoonix Why my query need use gen_clust_index？

Comment: I would've answered it if I had one for you.  You said you had no index.  That's incorrect.  Hope that helps.  Try [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @yoonix Thanks. I will post question to dba.stackexchange.